# How to parse two characters at a time for one Iteration?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a written query for matching 2 characters and parse the data but I feel that the way i did is wrong. Let me share my logic with you

```
DEFINE VARIABLE I                   AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cData               AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cParsData           AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN
       cData = 'PRRSCLPP0123456789'.

DO I = 1 TO LENGTH(cData):

   cParsData = SUBSTRING(cData,I).
   IF cParsData MATCHES 'PP*' THEN MESSAGE SUBSTRING(cParsData,4,9).

END.
```

As you see the way i did is wrong and its parsing each character per iteration i think but what i need is it should parse two characters per iteration so that we can matches "PP". You can share or change the logic for different ways to get the same output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to imagine a reason for iterating through the string one character at a time looking for "PP" and then spitting out characters 4 through 13.  It would be much simpler to do this:

```
define variable myData  as character no-undo.
define variable foundIt as integer   no-undo.

myData = "PRRSCLPP0123456789".

foundIt = index( myData, "PP" ).
if foundIt > 0 then 
  message substring( myData, 4, 9 ).
```

If there is a reason to go through that string one character at a time I think it must not be contained in your code sample or question.

On a side note: MATCHES "PP*" is equivalent to BEGINS "PP".  It doesn't matter much in this case but it is a bad habit to needlessly throw MATCHES at string comparisons.  Especially if that habit ends up in a WHERE clause.  Using MATCHES in WHERE clauses will cause a table scan.  Which is almost always a bad idea.

If you are trying to output N characters after the position that "PP" was found (rather than the hard-coded 4 through 13) you would do it like so (assuming that n = 9):

```
define variable myData  as character no-undo.
define variable foundIt as integer   no-undo.

myData = "PRRSCLPP0123456789".

foundIt = index( myData, "PP" ).
if foundIt > 0 then 
  message substring( myData, foundIt + 1, 9 ).
```

Comment: This is obviously a superior solution to mine iterative one. I'm still really struggling to understand the actual problem being solved though.

Comment: I'm mystified by that too.  If it is actually needed the reason is not (currently) present on this page.  The only explanation that I can think of is that as someone new to programming with Progress he has had no exposure to functions like INDEX() and thus decided to pull the string apart one character at a time.  In the good old days we could pop open "Pocket Progress" and easily find suitable functions.  In the brave new paperless world it's not so easy to just browse for likely suspects ;)

Comment: Yes. The lack of a namespace and or structured documentation (all about strings here, numbers here etc). Also makes it hard to know about whats available.

Answer (score 2):

I dont quite understand what you want to do. Do you want to search the string and see if there's "PP" in it? Then you don't need to do it in an iteration. Simply

`cData MATCHES "*PP*"` will tell you that.

If "PP" is some kind of delimiter and you want to do something with the data before and after you can do:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE I                   AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cData               AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO .
DEFINE VARIABLE cParsData           AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN
   cData = 'PRRSCLPP0123456789'.

DO I = 1 TO LENGTH(cData):

    cParsData = SUBSTRING(cData,I, 2).
    IF cParsData = 'PP' THEN DO:
        DISPLAY 
            SUBSTRING(cData, i + 2)    FORMAT "x(20)" LABEL "After PP" 
            SUBSTRING(cData, 1, i - 1) FORMAT "x(20)" LABEL "Before PP".
    END.

END.
```

This only works for one occurance of "PP" in the string though. You should try to explain better exactly what you are after.

You left a lot more information in a comment on another answer:
[image: Comment]

If PP really always is position 10 (and 11) or 20 (and 21) and you only want the follwing 10 chars then you can do:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cData1 AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cData2 AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
/* Position 10 and 11 */
cData1 = 'PRRSCLAAAPP0123456789'.
/* Position 20 and 21 */
cData2 = 'PRRSCLAAAPRRSCLAAAPP9876543210AA'.

FUNCTION parse  RETURNS CHARACTER 
    (INPUT cString AS CHARACTER ):
    IF INDEX(cString, "PP") > 0 THEN 
        RETURN SUBSTRING(cString, INDEX(cString, "PP") + 2, 10 ).
    ELSE 
        RETURN "".

END.

 MESSAGE cData1 " ->" parse(cData1) SKIP
         cData2 " ->" parse(cData2) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Comment: Thx Man. It's works also do we not to call DO loop as iteration?As you know each and every time the value of 'I' is changing based on length of cData. So I thought we can call this iteration and that's the reason i mentioned. Correct me if i am  wrong

Comment: `cParsData = SUBSTRING(cData,I, 2)` is looking at 2 bytes per iteration with i increasing so first iteration it looks at position 1 and 2, second iteration 2 and 3 etc. If that is what you need to do, not simply see that PP is in the string you need some kind of iteration yes.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the fixed positions mention in a comment on the other answer.

Comment: Hi Jensd, Thank you this is what i am looking for..and sorry for my bad knowledge because i am young and in starting stage to learn everything step by step